# Mapreduce job failing inside IntelliJ

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, mapreduce

I'm trying to run a Map-Reduce job from inside of IntelliJ. This is my runner code,

```
public class ViewCount extends Configured implements Tool{

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();


        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJobName("viewCount");
        job.setJarByClass(ViewCount.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        Path inputFilePath = new Path(args[0]);
        Path outputFilePath = new Path(args[1]);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputFilePath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputFilePath);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new ViewCount(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
```

The task fails to build with the following error message.

```
error: incompatible types: Job cannot be converted to JobConf
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputFilePath);
```

The Apached documents suggest that the method actually takes a job and not a JobConf, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: this has nothing to do with IntelliJ

Comment: You may be mixing map reduce 1 and 2 APIs. Check from where you are importing FileOutputFormat. Old mapreduce(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat) takes in JobConf whereas new one(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat) takes Job as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the packages the classes come from. You might be mixing packages and you need to use the TextInputFormat from the correct package according to your Hadoop version. If you are using Hadoop version 2.x then you need to import different classes ( from mapreduce  package) as compare to Hadoop version 1.x ( which had mapred package )